# How to send a 'write as proxy' transaction using the ABI for the implementation contract?

Tags: ether, etherscan, web3.py, python

i am trying to call the function `requestL2Transaction` of the contract `0x32400084C286CF3E17e7B677ea9583e60a000324`

The ABI is located at `0xc796a402e1b26ecd2cd38f23e05a2f904504ec89`

But I am getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\zksync.py", line 31, in <module>
    gas_estimate = contract.functions.requestL2Transaction(_contractL2, _l2Value, _calldata, _l2GasLimit, _l2GasPerPubdataByteLimit, _factoryDeps, _refundRecipient).estimateGas()
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1044, in estimateGas
    **self.kwargs
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1619, in estimate_gas_for_function
    return web3.eth.estimateGas(estimate_transaction, block_identifier)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 44, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str, params, error_formatters)
  File "\venv\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 158, in request_blocking
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': 3, 'message': 'execution reverted: mv', 'data': '0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000026d76000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'}
```

Here is my full code:

```
from web3 import Web3

provider = Web3.HTTPProvider('https://rpc.ankr.com/eth')
w3 = Web3(provider)

private_key = ''
my_address = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(private_key).address
contract_address = w3.toChecksumAddress('0x32400084C286CF3E17e7B677ea9583e60a000324')

abi = []
#I removed the entire ABI because it is very long, but rest assured that the ABI from 0xc796a402e1b26ecd2cd38f23e05a2f904504ec89 is here.

contract = w3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)

params = {
    'contractL2': my_address,
    'l2Value': 1150000000000000,
    'calldata': b'',
    'l2GasLimit': 1000000,
    'l2GasPerPubdataByteLimit': 800,
    'factoryDeps': [],
    'refundRecipient': my_address,
}

gas_estimate = contract.functions.requestL2Transaction(
    params['contractL2'], params['l2Value'], params['calldata'],
    params['l2GasLimit'], params['l2GasPerPubdataByteLimit'], params['factoryDeps'], params['refundRecipient']
).estimateGas()

transaction = {
    'from': my_address,
    'value': params['l2Value'],
    'gas': gas_estimate,
    'gasPrice': w3.eth.gasPrice,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
}

transaction_data = contract.functions.requestL2Transaction(
    params['contractL2'], params['l2Value'], params['calldata'],
    params['l2GasLimit'], params['l2GasPerPubdataByteLimit'], params['factoryDeps'], params['refundRecipient']
).buildTransaction(transaction)

signed_transaction = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction_data, private_key)
transaction_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_transaction.rawTransaction)
print(f"Transaction sent: {transaction_hash.hex()}")
```

I looked at other transactions and compared them to mine, and the data being passed is the same. Here is the decoding of a successful transaction:

[image]

I would appreciate your suggestions to resolve the issue and I would be happy if we find a solution together (we will definitely find one).

Answer (score 0):

I use this structure to create a transaction and it works for me:

`tx = contract.functions.requestL2Transaction(wallet_address, 10000000000000000000000, bytes(), 694246, 800, [], wallet_address)`

I think your error is related to estimateGas()

Answer (score 0):

From looking at https://etherscan.io/address/0xc796a402e1b26ecd2cd38f23e05a2f904504ec89#code

we can see where the `mv` error comes from.

line 272:

```
// Checking that the user provided enough ether to pay for the transaction.
// Using a new scope to prevent "stack too deep" error
{
            params.l2GasPrice = _isFree ? 0 : _deriveL2GasPrice(tx.gasprice, _l2GasPerPubdataByteLimit);
            uint256 baseCost = params.l2GasPrice * _l2GasLimit;
            require(msg.value >= baseCost + _l2Value, "mv"); // The `msg.value` doesn't cover the transaction cost
}
```

In your tx:

```
transaction = {
    'from': my_address,
    'value': params['l2Value'],
    'gas': gas_estimate,
    'gasPrice': w3.eth.gasPrice,
    'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
}
```

you would need to add the `baseCost` in order for the tx to be able to go through. Your code fail earlier though and I guess this is because `estimateGas()` does not run properly on this write function